# Target select option with value _none

Tags: jquery

```
$('select').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == '_none'){ 
    $(this).closest('div').addClass('HELLO-MATE');
  }
});
```

I have this set up to add a class to the surrounding div on the select list so I can add some CSS to it if the value is none.

The select html looks like this....

```
<select id="myselect" name="field_guest_list" class="form-select">
  <option value="_none">- None -</option>
</select>
```

The JS is being called, but the class isnt added anywhere. Can anyone see what im doing wrong?

Comment: What is your precise question? What do you mean "nothing happens"? Have you confirmed the code is getting called? You need to do some basic debugging, by the sounds of it.

Comment: Ive edited that last line for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('select').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '_none') {
          $(this).closest('div').addClass('HELLO-MATE');
        } else {
          $(this).closest('div').removeClass('HELLO-MATE');
        }
      }).trigger("change");
    });
```

```css
.HELLO-MATE {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="myselect" name="field_guest_list" class="form-select">
    <option value="_none">- None -</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here we are triggering the change event via `$.trigger("change")` as soon as we have attached the change event listener to execute our logic

Comment: Thanks, this looks perfect, but the select list I have doesn't have any other options apart from none, and the class isn't being added by default. Its not  setting the class here for some reason.

Comment: It should work. See I have modified the snippet and still its adding class via JS code. Please check code at your end.

Comment: yeah I agree, must be something else my end as your snippet works great. Thank you

Comment: its not because im using jquery 1.10.2 is it?

Comment: no...jQuery version doesn't matter. check whether CSS file got added correctly to the page or not. Just try to apply that class via inspect element of browser's developer tool and see if you get UI reflected.

Comment: Got it. Im in Drupal, and in an ajax behavior, which needed an associated jQuery Drupal behavior to run. Once i added that it worked, Thanks!

Comment: thats great @Collins...`:)`!